Opacity Blending Objects
Can someone please help me out? I drawed a line and circle. They are on top of each other. When I adjust the opacity of both objects I see darker parts when the circle and line collide.  How can I adjust this?
image

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What you are describing would be completely normal under most circumstances. What are you trying to achieve here?  If you want both objects to have the same transparency all over without interacting with each like that, then you could group fully opaque overlapping objects, and apply the transparency to the group instead. If this is what you are looking for I can add it as an answer.
